# Simplify this dictionary of lists into a single list containing all/only unique values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a dictionary with lists as values, like this:

```
my_dict = {"a": [1, 6, 8, 4],
           "b": [2, 7, 4, 9, 13],
           "c": [9, 5, 6, 8, 11]
          }
```

What I want is a list with one of each of the unique items in the lists from the dictionary.

So, `my_list` should be `[1, 6, 8, 4, 2, 7, 9, 13, 5, 11]`. I don't care about order.

I did it like this:

```
my_list = []
for k in my_dict:
    for item in my_dict[k]:
        if item not in my_list:
            my_list.append(item)
```

This works, but I feel like there is a more elegant solution, perhaps using a list comprehension.

Comment: Use set or hashes/dict to have O(N) complexity

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset); you can produce the union of all values with:

```
set().union(*my_dict.values())
```

Demo:

```
>>> my_dict = {"a": [1, 6, 8, 4],
...            "b": [2, 7, 4, 9, 13],
...            "c": [9, 5, 6, 8, 11]
...           }
>>> set().union(*my_dict.values())
set([1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13])
```

Sets have no order (just like dictionary keys are unordered), but you stated you don't care about the order of the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. Iterate dictionary.
2. extend list value in to list variable.
3. Use set method to remove duplicate items.

code:

```
>>> my_dict = {"a": [1, 6, 8, 4],
...            "b": [2, 7, 4, 9, 13],
...            "c": [9, 5, 6, 8, 11]
...           }
>>> my_list = []
>>> for k, v in my_dict.items():
...    my_list.extend(v)
... 
>>> my_list
[1, 6, 8, 4, 9, 5, 6, 8, 11, 2, 7, 4, 9, 13]
>>> my_list = list(set(my_list))
>>> my_list
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13]
>>>
```

---

by set operation.

```
>>> my_list = set()
>>> for i in my_dict.values():
...     my_list.update(i)
... 
set([1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13])
>>>
```

Comment: Why build a list first when you could just build a set instead? Your loop approach can easily use `my_set = set()` then `my_set.update(v)` in the loop, for example.

Comment: This works, but I find it only slightly more elegant.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yes correct. Thank you. Always do review of my code and give suggestion .